password_verify() returning false, even though both values are same
<?php

    $A = 'ABCD';
    $B = 'ABCD';

    $md5A = md5($A); //cb08ca4a7bb5f9683c19133a84872ca7
    $md5B = md5($B); //cb08ca4a7bb5f9683c19133a84872ca7


    echo "Using the password_verify() funtion\n";
    if (password_verify($md5A, $md5B)) {
        echo "True";
    } else {
        echo "False";
    }

    echo "\nUsing the Using the == copmparison\n";
    if ($md5A == $md5B) {
        echo "True";
    } else {
    echo "False";
    }

?>

password_verify() returning False, however the == comparison return true. What could be the issue for this problem.

That's not how password_verify() works. The first argument is an unhashed password, the second argument is a hashed password. It hashes the password and checks if that matches the hashed password.

You shouldn't be using md5 at all.

See the password_hash() doc page.

Not sure how you ended up trying to use it like this, except perhaps by not reading the documentation or looking carefully at any examples

The whole point of password functions is having salted passwords and different algorithms, so users with the same password will never get the same hash twice. If aren't using any of this, $md5A === $md5B is more than enough. Why not use raw MD5? Because you can simple google it.

That's not the correct way to demonstrate password_verify(). It requires the second argument to be a hashed password created by password_hash(), and the first argument should be the password to check. So the following is a proper test:
<?php

    $A = 'ABCD';
    $B = 'ABCD';

    $hashed_A = password_hash($A);

    echo "Using the password_verify() funtion\n";
    if (password_verify($B, $hashed_A)) {
        echo "True";
    } else {
        echo "False";
    }

    echo "\nUsing the Using the == copmparison\n";
    if ($A == $B) {
        echo "True";
    } else {
    echo "False";
    }
?>

There's no need to hash the passwords with MD5 first.
